# Get Specific arrays data using <select> element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Although there are already some questions related to this one but thing I could not found is " getting arrays data using <select> element". 
For Example ...There are 3 arrays

```html
<script>
function myCountry() {
var country_1 = ["city1", "city2", "city3"];
var country_2 = ["city2_1", "city2_2","city3_3"];
var country_3 = ["city3_1", "city3_2" ,"city3_3"];
}
</script>
```

Now  using HTML <select> Element.

```html
<select onchange="myCounty()">
<option>Country1</option>
<option>Country2</option>
<option>Country3</option>
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

I want that if  a specific country is selected (For Example 'Country1') then cities in array 1 (i.e. var country_1 = ["city1".....]) should be display in paragraph with id = demo (For Example)

Comment: Structure the data into a single 2D array instead of multiple variables, then add `value` attributes to `options` with values starting from `0`. then just retrieve the array `let some_var = arr[this.value]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you?

We first create an id for the `select` element. The get the index of the element being selected, then I create an array of arrays and access the corresponding index's array, then finally print the output with a comma.

Please let me know if this fixes your issue!

```js
var country_1 = ["city1", "city2", "city3"];
var country_2 = ["city2_1", "city2_2", "city3_3"];
var country_3 = ["city3_1", "city3_2", "city3_3"];

function myCountry() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("country");
  var options = [country_1, country_2, country_3];
  var index = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].index;
  var output = "";
  for( var k of options[index]){
    output += k + ", ";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output;
}
document.getElementById("country").addEventListener("change", myCountry);
myCountry();
```

```html
<select id="country">
<option>Country1</option>
<option>Country2</option>
<option>Country3</option>
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an array to grab some data that you want to get.

```js
function myCountry(index) {
    var country = [
        ["city1", "city2", "city3"],
        ["city2_1", "city2_2","city3_3"],
        ["city3_1", "city3_2" ,"city3_3"]
    ]
    
    return country[index];
}

var p = document.querySelector('p');
var select = document.querySelector('select');

p.innerHTML = myCountry(0);

select.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    p.innerHTML = myCountry(e.target.selectedIndex);
});
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Country1</option>
    <option>Country2</option>
    <option>Country3</option>
</select>

<p></p>
```